# Please help me understand the use of the same namespace in the code below

Tags: c++, namespaces

I used Code::Blocks to find the answer, and it gave me 42, which means B=4, and A=2; I understand why A=2, but I don't know why B=4, and not 5;
The code in C++ is below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace S
{
   int A = 1;
}

namespace S
{
   int B = A + 2;
}

int main()
{
   S::A = S::A+1;

   {
      using namespace S;
      ++B;
   }

   cout << S::B << S::A;
}
```

Comment: Even after fixing the "namspace" typo, [the code does not compile](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72dc39182a7ad1dc). Present a _real_ [mcve], copy/pasted from your editor.

Comment: @painkiller The program is invalid because in this statement  S::A=A+1; there is used undeclared variable A in the right side of the assignment.

Comment: I fixed the mistake, it's  S::A = S::A+1.

Comment: Are you aware that `S::B` is initially `3` ( = 1 + 2)? `using namespace` is not like a function call. It just pulls identifiers into current namespace. That's relevant for compiler (how symbols are looked up / resolved) but not a runtime.

Comment: You may try print-debugging: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e581a078faea4273).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with namespaces.

A and B are two separate, independent variables.

During startup, you set A to 1, then B to 3 (the result of calculating A+2 at that point).

Then you add one to A, to get 2.

**B is not "linked" to A in any way, so this assignment to A does not affect B.**

Then you increment B, to 4.

Answer (score 4):

The only steps you're doing with B are:

```
int B = A + 2; //from this point B == 3 since 1 + 2 == 3;
...
++B; //now B == 4 because it was incremented by 1 (++ operator);
```

Namespaces have nothing to do here, you can affect B only when you refer to it (unless using references or pointers but not here).

Comment: But what if instead of tre ++B statement, it would be written B+=A+3 ? then it would be: B= B+A+3 = 3+2+3= 8 ?

Comment: A this step `A` would be already `2` so ->  `A+3` would be `5` so -> `B` would be `3 + 5 == 8`, yes.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the mechanism.